# Prevent a macOS bar from having a sidebar

Tags: macos, swiftui

By default the first list added to a view seems to be set to sidebar. Even if you don't specifically call `.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())`.

Is there any way that the list you set on the view (even if it's the first view) is not set to a sidebar? There is no indication on the Apple's documentation, and anything I have tried to style the list is not working.

So instead of the list looking like this:

[image]

It should look like:

[image]

## Edit:

Yes, code. Any simple code will do.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: TextEView(),
                ) {
                    Text("One")
                }
        }
    }    
}

struct TextEView: View {
    @State private var fullText: String = "This is some editable text..."
    var body: some View {        
         TextEditor(text: $fullText)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just don't include that List into NavigationView

Comment: @Asperi how would you navigate the list then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case try

```
    List {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: TextEView(),
            ) {
                Text("One")
            }
    }
    .listStyle(.plain) // << here !!
```